# How to switch to long mode in OS development?

Tags: c++, operating-system

So, a while ago, I started an operating system project. So far, I have a multiboot-compatible 32 bit OS and would like to switch it up to 64 bit.

I'm using GRUB, installed via Linux, to boot the OS kernel (which is in 32 bit code), and would like to know how to switch to a 64 bit kernel instead (that is, how to boot a 64 bit kernel through GRUB).

Comment: App and OS usage questions (vs. programming) usually belong at SuperUser.com or for this case one of the linux sites - https://stackexchange.com/sites

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Alright, so going back to the OS Dev website, I did find some guidelines on how to acheive 64 bit long mode. I decided to go with changing from GRUB2 to Limine as my bootoader.